# How do I get data out of the "data" variable in jQuery and Django

Tags: ajax, django, jquery

I think it goes a little something like this:

In my view:

```
from django.core import serializers
```

And later....

```
data = serializers.serialize('json', MODEL.objects.filter(id=id), fields=('points'))
return HttpResponse(data)
```

In my jQuery:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
  dataType: "json"
});

$('#selector .selector_detail a').click(function() {
    var call_to = $(this).attr('href');

    $.ajax({
      url: call_to,
      type: "POST",

      complete: function() {
          console.log('Ajax Complete')
      },

      success: function(data) {
          points = data(fields.points)
          console.log('Ajax Successful')
          console.log(data);
     },

      error: function(xhr) {
          console.log('Whoops, something went wrong. XHR Response:' + JSON.stringify(xhr));
      },
    });

    return false;
});
```

I want the value of points, but I have no idea how to get it out. I can see it in the console.log when I look at the data Objects. What am I missing?

Comment: What does the `console.log` statement print? I'm guessing `data` either *is* the `points` object or contains a property `points`.

Comment: it prints out: '[{"pk": 3, "model": "pointify.hero", "fields": {"points": 2758}}]'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if data is a json object and the correct headers are set, you can access it's properties using a dot:

```
data.points

data[0].points  //if points is an array
//this is not correct
data(fields.points);
```

I don't know what's the exact structure of 'data' but you can derive it from your console.log(data);

EDIt - if data has the structure you outlined in the comment you can access points like this:

```
 alert(data[0].fields.points);
```

Comment: this is what I get from data:

'[{"pk": 4, "model": "pointify.hero", "fields": {"points": 3102}}]'

I'm pretty new at this, so I'm not sure how to hit the points in fiels. It looks like an array in an array?

Comment: Awesome!!! Thanks so much. Quick question about the [0]. Doesn't that indicate the number in the array? I was trying to get at position [3] (#4 in a 0 based count) but that doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Yes, it means position number 0 (that is the first object in the array. Actually maybe you have problem with position number 3 because maybe the array is not made up of four objects. 'data' seems to be an array of objects, you can check it's length with data.length;

Answer (score 0):

add dataType: 'json' to your .ajax call.

```
$.ajax({
  url: call_to,
  dataType: 'json',
  type: "POST",
```

then its jut data.points in your success function, or perhaps data.field.points. I can't tell from your post.